# how to insert data into database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to insert data into one table, my table have three columns, id-auto increment, phoneno, login_date. i am trying the below code.

```
$input = Request::has('phoneno');
$login_history = new LoginHistory;
$login_history->phoneno=$input;
$login_history->login_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$login_history->save();
```

but i am getting the below error.

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `login_history` (`phoneno`, `login_date`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2015-12-14 08:55:25, 2015-12-14 08:55:25, 2015-12-14 08:55:25))

Answer (score 2):

You don't have **created_at** and **updated_at** columns in your table that **Eloquent** expects all models have by default. Either create those columns or simply disable timestamps for that model by setting **$timestamps** property accordingly:

```
class LoginHistory {
  protected $timestamps = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you do not have the field `updated_at` in your database table.
Make sure to add:

`$table->timestamps()`

to your migration and re-migrate the database ( or update the table ).

This will add the fields `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error is simple. Laravel by default assumes that your table has `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. hence, `->save()` method tries to store the timestamps as you can see in the query.

If you do not want these to be included, add `public $timestamps = false;` in your Model.